# How to grab substring after a specific word in java

Tags: java

I'm creating an IRC bot that grabs Twitter links and sends the text to the channel. This is my code:

```
if (messageIC.contains("https://twitter.com/") && messageIC.contains("/status/")) {
    try {
        String tweeter = message.substring(20);
        String[] tweety = tweeter.split(" ");
        String tweety1 = tweety[0];
        String url = "https://twitter.com/" + tweety1;
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Element tweetText = doc.select("p.js-tweet-text.tweet-text").first();
        sendMessage(channel, "Twitter: " + tweetText.text());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Ampersand.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

This works if the user sends only the link or even if the user types something out after the link. But it doesn't work if the user types something before the link, for example, "blahblahblah http://www.twitter.com/user/status/xxxx" since it will start grabbing immediately and not after twitter.com.

Is there a way to only grab the substring after twitter.com?

Comment: Yes, there is multiple ways

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` and `substring`. First get the start of the link by getting the index of `"https://twitter.com/"`. Then you look for a space after the beginning of the link, if one exists link ends there, otherwise it ends at the end of the `message`. Then we can use the `substring` method to get the link:

```
int startIndex = message.indexOf("https://twitter.com/");
int endIndex = message.indexOf(" ", startIndex);
if (endIndex == -1) {
    endIndex = message.length();
}
String link = message.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```

Another easy way, `split` everything by space and check if they match the requirements:

```
String[] words = message.split(" ");
for (String word : words) {
    if (word.startsWith("https://twitter.com/")) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain this code? If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner is more likely to learn something!

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I'll add something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use String's [`indexOf(String str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) method to find where the `http://etc` is. You can then use [`indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-) method to find where the first space after the URL is. Lastly, use [`substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) with those two values.

I won't give you the full code; you'll learn by writing it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Use the String `indexOf(String s)` method on the full string. Then add that int to the length of the target String (in this case `"www.twitter.com"`) and use that as the starting index for your substring.

```
String s = "http://www.twitter.com/user/status/xxxx";
String target = "www.twitter.com";
int index = s.indexOf(target);
int subIndex = index + target.length();
System.out.print(s.substring(subIndex));
```